# sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container - is there a way to configure underlying tensorflow_model_server REST API timeout

Tags: tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

TensorFlow Model Server has a command-line option '--rest_api_timeout_in_ms' that controls the timeout for its rest api. I believe by default this is 30 seconds. I am serving a (slow) TF model with sagemaker-tensorflow-container (https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container) and getting timeouts from the underlying tensorflow model server process (which is started by the sagemaker container, see here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container/blob/3952606048615297e5629b2b27dfa6557616b986/docker/build_artifacts/sagemaker/serve.py#L178

Looking at the sagemaker-tensorflow-container source I do not see a way to supply this '--rest_api_timeout_in_ms' option :-(.

If anyone faced this or similar problem, I would really appreciate any hints or possible workarounds. Thanks!